# There is a group such that satisfy the maximal permutizer condition but not satisfy the permutizer condition ?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$ P_{G}(H) = \langle g\in G \ \vert \langle g \rangle H = H \langle g \rangle \rangle $ called the permutizer subgroup $ H $ of $ G $. $ G $ is satisfy the permutizer condition if $ H < P_{G}(H) $ for any proper subgroup $ H $ of $ G $. $ G $ said satisfy the maximal permutizer condition if $ P_{G}(M)=G $ for any maximal subgroup $ M $ of $ G $. $ G $ is satisfy the permutizer condition then $ G $ satisfy the maximal permutizer condition. There is a group such that satisfy the maximal permutizer condition but not satisfy the permutizer condition ?

Comment: This was also asked here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203775 but nobody knew an example!

Comment: @DerekHolt You are said $ S_{3} $ satisfy the maximal permutizer condition but i think $ P_{S_{3}}(A_{3}) = A_{3} $.

Comment: $N_G(H) \le P_G(H)$ and $N_G(A_3)=S_3$.

Comment: I found an example - see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203775